# read/write OpenOffice image title and description from LibreOffice 5

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice-writer

I have many documents created in OpenOffice Writer that contain images with title and description.

[image: image rightclick menu of OpenOffice Writer]

Is there a way to read and modify these using LibreOffice Writer 5? I looked, but I didn't yet find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the entry was removed from the context menu, but it is still in the main menu bar.  First select the image, then go to Format -> Object -> Description.